# Any example of a custom PreProcessor in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I've walked through the cabal `Distribution.Simple*` packages to know that the `PreProcessor` data type can be used to defined custom pre-processors. But the example provided is not so useful. I don't know how to invoke the pre-processor.

Currently, I just define my own pre-processors in the `Setup.hs` file.

Are there any complete examples for this feature?

---

***[EDITED]***
Check [this](http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/12911379.html) mail-list archive I just found. But the solution involves transforming from one type of file (identified by the extension of that file) to another.

What I want to do is to inject code into existing `.hs` files where a custom mark is defined, e.g.

```
-- <inject point="foo">
-- extra Haskell code goes here
-- </inject>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the most important things to do is setting your BuildType in your .Cabal file to Custom. If it stays at Simple Cabal will completely ignore the Setup.hs file.

```
Build-Type:     Custom
```

Here is an example Custom preprocessor from my package, It first runs cpphs and then runs hsc2hs

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
> {-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

> import Distribution.Simple
> import Distribution.Simple.PreProcess
> import Distribution.Simple.Utils
> import Distribution.PackageDescription
> import Distribution.Simple.LocalBuildInfo
> import Data.Char
> import System.Exit
> import System.IO
> import System.Directory
> import System.FilePath.Windows

> main = let hooks = simpleUserHooks 
>            xpp   = ("xpphs", ppXpp)
>        in defaultMainWithHooks hooks { hookedPreProcessors = xpp:knownSuffixHandlers  }
>
> ppXpp :: BuildInfo -> LocalBuildInfo -> PreProcessor 
> ppXpp build local =
>    PreProcessor {
>      platformIndependent = True,
>      runPreProcessor = mkSimplePreProcessor $ \inFile outFile verbosity ->
>        do info verbosity (inFile++" is being preprocessed to "++outFile)
>           let hscFile = replaceExtension inFile "hsc"
>           runSimplePreProcessor (ppCpp build local) inFile  hscFile verbosity
>           handle <- openFile hscFile ReadMode
>           source <- sGetContents handle
>           hClose handle
>           let newsource = unlines $ process $ lines source
>           writeFile hscFile newsource
>           runSimplePreProcessor (ppHsc2hs build local) hscFile outFile verbosity
>           removeFile hscFile
>           return ()
>      }
```

This preprocessor will automatically be called by Cabal when any file with the extension .xpphs is found.

In your case just register the preprocessor with a .hs extension. (I'm not sure if Cabal allows this. But if it doesn't you can simply rename the files with the injection point to a .xh or something. This would actually be better since you don't process *every* file in your project then)

Comment: Thanks! I finally figured out a solution which uses `preBuild` hook to generate the module using a template file as input. And then import this module where it supposed to be.