# "Bootstrapping" with Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

Imagine an Makefile like the following:

```
stage1 : Stage1.hs
       ghc -o stage1 Stage1.hs
Stage1.hs : stage0 
       stage0 > Stage1.hs
stage0 : Stage0.hs
       ghc -o stage0 Stage0.hs
```

The current directory would contain Makefile and Stage0.hs at first,and produce stage1.

Here are the questions:

1. How can I do the above entirely within Cabal? Am I supposed to do this only with hooks?
   (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370029/any-example-of-a-custom-preprocessor-in-haskell) or [this](http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/12911379.html).)
   What if the hook must depend on another program in the package to be built?
2. What if Setup.hs becomes complicated enough that it requires its own
   dependency management?
3. Is there a cabalized package that does similar things? If Happy included a cabalized test      program that depended on Happy invocation, that would have been a perfect example.

Comment: In the case of Happy and Alex, Cabal already knows how to deal with those, so you just need to list the modules in `Exposed-Modules` or `Other-Modules` and Cabal will generate the `.hs` files and compile them automatically.

Comment: That's true. I should perhaps mentioned [preprocessor-tools](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/preprocessor-tools) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cabal is tricky when it comes to situations like these.

As you said, if you can squeeze everything into `Setup.hs`, you'll keep the number of headaches you'll get to a minimum.

If you have *really* complicated preprocessors, I would suggest doing this:

1. Make one cabal package for each preprocessor, with its own dependencies etc. So, for `stage0`, you would have a cabal file like this:

   ```
   Name:
     mypackage-stage0
   Version:
     0.1
   -- ...

   Executable mpk-stage0
     Default-language:
       Haskell2010
     Main-is:
       Stage0.hs
     -- ...
   ```
2. For `stage1`, you need to generate the source code, so add a `preBuild` hook in your `Setup.hs` for `mypackage-stage1` that runs the `mpk-stage0` executable:

   ```
   main =
     defaultMainWithHooks simpleUserHooks
     { preBuild =
         -- ... something involving `system "mpk-stage1 Stage1.hs"`
         -- Note that shell redirection `> bla.hs` doesn't necessarily work
         -- on all platforms, so make your `mpk-stage1` executable take an
         -- output file argument
     }
   ```

   You'd then add a build-tool dependency on the previous stage:

   ```
   Executable mpk-stage1
     -- ...
     Main-is:
       Stage1.hs
     Build-tools:
       mypackage-stage0
   ```

   This should work in recent cabal versions; otherwise, you might have to add a `Build-depends:` dependency instead.
3. You *will* need to rebuild each package in turn every time you do a cascading change (This is necessary because cabal doesn't manage cross-project dependency changes), so you need a script that does `for project in mypackage-stage0 mypackage-stage1; do (cd $project; cabal install); done` or something similar.

Cabal was never built for this kind of project, so it **will** be tricky if you want to do something like this. You should look into using Template Haskell instead if you want to generate code in a more coherent way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, and I'm sorry for being late. That Cabal was never built for this kind of project was indeed what I suspected. FYI, my temporary solution was to add a flag to each executable, and use the master Makefile.am to drive the compilation. Your suggestion seems an improvement, but pops up

Comment: other questions. What if I didn't want to install stage0 in the user's system? Is it possible to register a temporary package locally in the build system? Does Template Haskell support multi-stage code generation? Lastly,am I supposed to write here as comments if I found answers myself? Or post another Answer answering my own question? Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, you can't make temporary executables. Template Haskell can be used in multiple stages; you can use TH to generate TH code which generates Haskell code. If you think your answer will help others, you should post your own answer.